# encrypt query string params in grails

Tags: java, security, grails, encryption

**I'm not depending on this as a primary layer of security or even one that i would be comfortable alone** but it would be just another layer to obfuscate how things work.

I was wondering if there was something already built that would allow me to encrypt the query string params in grails?  It would be easy enough to write something to do this but just looking for anything that might already be available.

something like...

```
<g:link controller="pony" action="ride" params="[thing:thingInstance.id.encrypt()]" />Go</g:link>
```

user sees `..\pony\ride\MaybeSomeMD5EncodedStringHere` instead of `..\pony\ride\1`

```
class PonyController{

    @Secured(['ROLE_AUTH_USER'])
    def ride ={
        //additional security checks handled by Spring Security Core
        def thing = Thing.get(thingInstance.id.dencrypt());
    }

}
```

Comment: who are you trying to encrypt things against?  The people who might be snooping on the user? (if so, I'd just use https, GET parameters are encrypted then)  Are you worried about the user seeing the parameters and just looking to obfuscate them?  How is the user knowing the key is "DingDong..." any different than them just knowing it's "1"?

Comment: Just looking to obfuscate them for a somewhat more secure query string.  The "DingDong" was just a example of a possible md5 encryption string.

Comment: OK, but more secure against who?  Who is the untrusted person that you are trying to protect against?  Your user who can legitimately go to the show action, or a 3rd party that might be snooping on the user?  If it's the first, this scheme adds no real security, if it's the second, you should be using https

Comment: Okay i see.  There is now real untrusted person, just hiding/obfuscating how things work.  It sounds like this has no use if other standards are utilized like https?

Comment: Right. GET parameters are encrypted over https so you're safe from 3rd parties.  You trust your user enough to give them access to the show action, and there's no advantage to obfuscating the ID of the object from them as you've already given them everything they need to access the resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your users should not be able to inflict harm by changing the request made.  You application should be doing its job securing every request based on permissions and roles, not just making sure you don't show the link /Users/delete/1 .  That controller should *actually check your permission to do that* regardless.

Anyway, there aren't any plug ins that I'm aware of for obfuscating the URL, probably because it would be so easy to roll your own.  Just edit your URLMappings:

http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html

And do something like convert it into Base64, that will probably obfuscate it enough.

```
encoded = s.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
```

Remember, this isn't a solid form of security, so if you need that and this is your plan of action, you're doing it wrong.

;)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I updated my questions stating my intentions better.

Comment: @Nate I have the same scenario, could you please clarify the answer more?

Comment: how i can edit the mapping file to add the hashing (encryption/description) mechanism